# How can I divide work read from a file to threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list of hosts and a list of ports.
I want to run X threads that will grab a single host every time and try to connect to these ports.
I got the connection part covered, my problem is how to thread it.
When I did some research I got really confused between threading, multiproccessing and asyncio.
What would be the most optimal and/or easy library?

right now my pseudo code no threaded code is:

```
def getHosts():
    hosts = open("hostList.txt").read().splitlines()
    return hosts
def getPorts():
    ports = open("portList.txt").read().splitlines()

hosts = getHosts()
ports = getPorts()
for host in hosts
    for port in ports
        ---the connection code---
```

I think my general idea is to take the length of the list, divide it by number of threads and create a thread that will run from thread_number*result_of_divide until (thread_number+1)*result_of_divide.

Comment: Note that threading and asyncio would not allow running code in parallel because of [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). So for parallel execution, you will need multiprocessing (or another programming language :))

Comment: Take a look on [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor).

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych
Thank you for your help and, GIL is very interesting and I hope I'll make it using ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor).

```
import concurrent.futures

MAX_THREAD_COUNT = 10


def read_text_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()


def check_port(host, port):
    pass


hosts = read_text_file("hostList.txt")
ports = read_text_file("portList.txt")


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_THREAD_COUNT) as executor:
    results = {}
    for host in hosts:
        for port in ports:
            results[executor.submit(check_port, host, port)] = "{}:{}".format(host, port)

for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
    host_and_port = results[result]
    try:
        returned_data = result.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print("\"{}\" exception have been caused while checking {}".format(e, host_and_port))
    else:
        print("Checking of {} returned {}".format(host_and_port, returned_data))
```

**P.S.** Code could be not 100% correct, I've not checked it "in action".

Comment: This is great!
I copied it, played with it and then deleted and wrote from "scratch" and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @AviShabat, hope you understood how it works, not just copied ;)

Comment: Thats why I said I copied, played and deleted.
I copied to see how it works, played to check what I can do with it and wrote a completely new script.
I had errors and fixed them which helped me understand and remember better.