# How to add keyword arguments to methods called through ThreadPoolExecuter and run_in_executor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying to send a POST request concurrently with the help of `concurrent.futures`. For some reason, I am unable to set custom headers. I want to set

1. `Authorization`
2. `Content-type`

Here is the progress that I have made till now.

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus


params = urlencode({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "*/*","Authorization": "Bearer kdjalskdjalskd"}

async def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                requests.post,
                'https://fac03c95.ngrok.io',params, headers)
            for i in range(20)
        ]
        for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
            print(response.text)
            pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

But for some reason, the headers don't seem to show up in the request. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug lies in the way you pass in parameters for the `requests.post` call:

```
loop.run_in_executor(
    executor, 
    requests.post, 
    'https://fac03c95.ngrok.io',
    params, 
    headers
)
```

The requests post request expects keyword arguments for additional parameters such as headers as it seems from the [function header](http://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=post#requests.post). Now unfortunately the `loop.run_in_executor` call only accepts `*args` but not keyword arguments (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)) which makes it slightly more tricky to get it work correctly.

Personally, I would just write a little wrapper function for the requests call. It could look something like the following:

```
def make_request(url, data, headers):
    return requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

And call `make_request` instead of `request.post` from your asynchronous call. If we integrate it into your overall script, it could therefore looks something like the following:

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus


params = urlencode({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'})
headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Authorization": "Bearer kdjalskdjalskd"
}

def make_request(url, data, headers):
    return requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

async def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                make_request, 
                'https://fac03c95.ngrok.io', 
                params, 
                headers
            )
            for i in range(20)
        ]

        for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
            print(response.text)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Of course, you can add `*args` to `make_request` and pass in arguments from your function call - just keep in mind that only regular arguments are supported, not keyword arguments. Any function you wish to execute through your event loop that requires keyword arguments will need to be called through a wrapper.

---

### Recommended Approach in the Documentation

The recommended way according to the [`concurrent.futures` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to pass in keyword arguments to `func` is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) (as also pointed out in the other answer).

An example utilising `functools.partial` would look as follows.

```
from functools import partial

loop.run_in_executor(executor, partial(requests.post, data=params, headers=headers)
```

Whilst the result is the same as using a wrapper function, the advantage of using partial is that reduced duplication of two function calls into one as we don't need to pass the arguments through a wrapper function anymore.

Comment: I think, you should return something.

Comment: You're right of course, I forgot to add the return statement in the wrapper function. Just updated the code above.

Comment: It will be also great to not hardcode all arguments of `requests.post()`.

Comment: Well, this is just following the code posted in the question where the arguments were hard coded. It's up to the poster to improve code quality in this regard.

Comment: It's hardcoded in function call, so they have to left there (be passed into wrapper function).

Comment: Other [docs](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/#callback-style) show lambda as example. *Btw, it's bad practice to edit answer including part of another answer.*

Comment: Your answer did solve the header problem. But I am still not able to make requests concurrently. Is there some kind of overhead for every request?

Comment: @M.S.P, why do you use asyncio? `ThreadPoolExecutor` should be enough to let python send requests parallel.

Comment: @Olvin-Roght, ThreadPoolExecutor isn't able to send thoes requests concurrently. I am still facing some overhead. Perhaps you can help me here. Do you have some resources?

Comment: @M.S.P, it's able for sure. That's the reason why it exists. Even [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) in official docs show it. You can also check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55922892/10824407) where I've used ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 5):

***Disclaimer:*** It's solution of particular problem described in question. Improving quality of provided code is not an object of this answer.

Let's check docs of [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) and [`requests.post()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post).

`run_in_executor()` pass provided arguments to function. Now let's take a look on your code:

```
loop.run_in_executor(executor, requests.post, 'https://fac03c95.ngrok.io', params, headers)
```

So as a result function will be called like this:

```
requests.post('https://fac03c95.ngrok.io', params, headers)
```

Let's merge values of provided arguments with their keywords:

- **url** - `https://fac03c95.ngrok.io`;
- **data** - `{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}`
- **json** - `{"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ...}`

To add custom headers you should pass keyword argument `headers=`. Unfortunately, `run_in_executor()` doesn't forward keyword arguments, so you have to use some kind of proxy function. Here is few variants:

1. **Function**.

   ```
   def proxy_post(url, data, headers):
       return requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

   ...

   loop.run_in_executor(executor, proxy_post, 'https://fac03c95.ngrok.io', params, headers)
   ```
2. **lambda**.

   ```
   loop.run_in_executor(executor, lambda: requests.post('https://fac03c95.ngrok.io', data=params, headers=headers))
   ```
3. [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

   ```
   import functools

   ...

   loop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(requests.post, 'https://fac03c95.ngrok.io', data=params, headers=headers))
   ```

Comment: Using a lambda feels great! Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelLee, `lambda` is the most compact solution, but it's recommended to use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) . Quote: *"Use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) [to pass keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio-pass-keywords) to func."*